# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when call ktor server method

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have started ktor server instance on localhost 8081 port
app.conf

```
ktor {
    deployment {
        port = 8081
        port = ${?PORT}
    }
    application {
        modules = [ server.AdminModuleKt.adminModule ]
    }
    hikariconfig = "resources/dbconfig.properties"
}
    jwt {
        secret = "secret"
        issuer = "http://0.0.0.0:8081/"
        audience = "http://0.0.0.0:8081/admin/audience"
        realm = "Access to 'audience'"
    }
```

Server starts normal, but when i tries to call any method it respond only `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`
Method example

```
        get(BASE_PATH.plus(PING_PATH)) {
            call.response.status(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            call.respond("Service available")
        }
```

It works fine, but in one moment it start to send empty responses.
Main class
`fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)`

In `build.gradle`
`mainClassName = "io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain"`

Comment: I'm not sure wether `call.response.status()` is a valid code, I set status code during respond: `call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Service available")`

Comment: @PhilDukhov maybe this part is really wrong. Change code to ```call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Service available")``` but still returns empty response

Comment: have you tried adding logs, to see if your request is matched by `get(BASE_PATH.plus(PING_PATH))`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in dependencies conflicts.
I had kotlinx serialization version 2+ and other features version 1.6.x
That is why `routing` in `Application` didn't work with DSL error
`@[ERROR : io.ktor.util.pipeline.ContextDsl]`
Making all feature dependencies 1.6.x has solved the problem